# Proof the sequence $(x_n)=\frac{n}{n+1}$ is contractive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

After proving $(x_n)=(\frac{n}{n+1}:n\in \Bbb N^+)$ is convergent, a bounded, monotone, and Cauchy sequence. Next I have to prove that this sequence is contractive. Though I have no idea if it is true or false right now. I read some examples on how to do it, most of it are about defining $x_{n+1}$ first, but I don't know how to do that for this sequence.

So I don't even know how to begin proving this.

Comment: Define 'contractive'.

Comment: Define "defining $x_{n+1}$", since it should be clear that $x_{n+1} = \frac {n+1}{n+2}$, and you must have used this in your previous proofs.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I believe, he is treating the sequence as a function on $\mathbb{N}$ and take the general definition of a [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping)

Comment: I used Bartle book for studying so the definition in that book is "We say that a sequence $X=(x_n)$ is contractive if there exists a constant $C$, $0<C<1$ such that $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\le C|x_{n+1}-x_n|$

Answer (score 1):

$$|x_{n+1}-x_n| = \left|\frac {n+1}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right| = \left|\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}\right|$$
hence
$$\frac {|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|}{|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|} = \frac {(n+1)(n+2)}{(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac {n+1}{n+3} = 1-\frac 2{n+3}$$

Now, does there exist any $0 < C < 1$ such that the above is bounded above by $C$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\vert x_n-x_m\vert=\dfrac{\vert n-m \vert}{(m+1)(n+1)}\le\dfrac{\vert n-m\vert}{4}.$$ Becouse the minimum value of $(m+1)(n+1)$ achieve at $n=m=1.$